# Css code for header Joomla

Tags: css, joomla, header, customization

I have been trying to edit my header in Joomla. I have added following class to my template to round the corners and add the background:

```
.holola {
background: #FFF!important;
border-top-left-radius: 15px;
border-top-right-radius: 15px; }
```

How I can bring the logo up and make it look offside the header, like in attached image. I know how to make this happen using image in header, but I want to make it pure CSS to make the page look better in mobile version.

I have tried to add padding but I think it should be more complicated code to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the padding you've added.

Then add some top margin to the .wrapper to push the main content down a bit.

```
body.boxed .wrapper {
    margin: 60px auto 0 auto
}
```

And now add margin-top to the logo to move it up.

```
#header_logo {
    margin-top: -60px
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these also

```
#zo2-header{

    margin-top: 50px;
}

#header_logo .logo_normal{
   position: absolute;
   top: -103px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `padding: 60px 0;` from #zo2-header and replace with `margin-top: 60px;`.

Add 
`#header_logo {
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use [position relative](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp). See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxnh6eef/) for a simple example that should work for you situation.

```
#img {
    background-color:red;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    position:relative;
    top: -40px;
}
```

Basically the important parts here is the combination of position: relative and top: -40px. This says position the element relative to the parent element and "anchor" its top -40 pixels from where it would normally be (top aligned with the header's top)